# Rails Heroku - unable to git push heroku master - i18n issue

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to git push heroku master.

It's failing with the following error:

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.10 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I have i18n in my gemfile.lock file. Does anyone know what to do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when the Gem author has yanked the specific version of the Gem that you are using. Indeed http://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/versions confirms this.

You would need to update (downgrade) to the previous version and then commit the new Gemfile.lock and redeploy your application.

Answer (score 6):

In your `gemfile.lock` change

```
i18n (0.6.10)
```

to

```
i18n (0.6.9)
```

As John Beynon mentioned there is no current version of 0.6.10.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know where this is coming from as well.  My Gemfile.lock has the following.

```
$grep i18n Gemfile.lock 
    i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
    i18n (~> 0.5)
  i18n (0.6.10)
```

And after reversing the dependencies it shows this. Can anyone shed light on why 0.6.10 is there?

```
$ gem dependency i18n --reverse-dependencies
Gem i18n-0.6.9
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0, development)
  mocha (>= 0, development)
  sqlite3 (>= 0, development)
  test_declarative (>= 0, development)
  Used by
    activesupport-4.1.1 (i18n (>= 0.6.9, ~> 0.6))
    activesupport-4.0.2 (i18n (>= 0.6.4, ~> 0.6))
    faker-1.1.2 (i18n (~> 0.5))
    rails-i18n-4.0.1 (i18n (~> 0.6))

Gem i18n-0.6.10
  Used by
    activesupport-4.1.1 (i18n (>= 0.6.9, ~> 0.6))
    activesupport-4.0.2 (i18n (>= 0.6.4, ~> 0.6))
    faker-1.1.2 (i18n (~> 0.5))
    rails-i18n-4.0.1 (i18n (~> 0.6))
```

Rather than changing the lock file, I tied down the ref in Gemfile to 0.6.9, did bundle update and then commit and pushed.  Same solution .. but now Gemfile.lock is more reflective of my Gemfile

```
gem 'i18n', '0.6.9' # added to Gemfile
bundle update i18n
git commit -am 'updated Gemfile ref for i18n heroku push bug'
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I `git clone repositary` and tried `bundle install`. I was getting error:

**Could not find i18n-0.6.10 in any of the sources**

Then I delete `Gemfile.lock` and again try `bundle install` and it works like charm..!!